# Determine if $g(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y}(4x+3y)$ is homogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

i have a doubt with this two exercises:

a) $g(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y}(4x+3y)$ is homogeneous?

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ then $g(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\sqrt{\lambda x+\lambda y}(4\lambda x+3\lambda y)=\sqrt{\lambda(x+y)}(\lambda(4x+3y))=\lambda^{\frac{3}{2}}\sqrt{x+y}(4x+3y)=\lambda^{\frac{3}{2}}g(x,y)$ then $g$ is homogeneous of grade $\frac{3}{2}$. Is correct this?.

b) $f(x,y)=\frac{\ln(x^3)}{\ln(y^3)}$

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f(\lambda x, \lambda y)=\frac{\ln(\lambda^3x^3)}{\ln(\lambda^3y^3)}=\frac{\ln(\lambda^3)+\ln(x^3)}{\ln(\lambda^3)+\ln(y^3)}\not =\lambda^nf(x,y)$ then $f$ is not homogeneous.

I have serious doubt in this two exercise, can someone help me?

Comment: yes it is correct, what is your doubt?

Comment: Neither example works if $\lambda<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct by the definition of [homogeneous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function).

Comment: In the first example, 3/2 is not an integer, does this matter?

Comment: @IntegrateThis not necessarly an integer